# HTML Three-page layout column gaps issue

Tags: css, html, web

On my project website I'm doing a three column layout, with assistance I received here I was able to get pretty far.

This is my website:

http://younani.com/finalsite/aboutus.html

I am trying to make my three column layout similar to the picture provided, but my problem is the left, right, and center column. When I put a background color on the left column as you can see it creates a gap between the center and the right, same goes for the left.

It looks really unprofessional and not clean, and I don't get why their is a gap in between all columns, and why I can't evenly match them. Same goes with the header. Any ideas why?

[image]

Below is my CSS:

```
#header {text-align: center;}


#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #FAFAFA;
     color: #003300;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-image:url('backgroundflower5.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;

}

#h2 {text-align: center;}

#container {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #container div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }


        #header {}


#center2 {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px; width: 494px; border-radius:8px;
        }


        #left,
        #center,
        #right {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }

        #center {font-family: Josefin Slab; background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 494px; border-radius:8px; text-align: center;
        } 

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

#right { font-family: Josefin Slab; font-weight:bold; border-radius:8px; background-color: #FBEFFB;}

#left a {text-decoration: none;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         color: #000000;
         font-weight:bold;
         border: 3px outset #FFFFFF;
         padding: 5px;}

figure{}

#left a:link { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:visited { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:hover {border: 3px inset #333333; }

#left ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }



#footer { text-align: center; font-family: Audimat;
    clear: both; width:38%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color:white;
        text-align:center; margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a 20px margin set for each column. If you don't want that space between them, change this code:

```
#left, #center, #right {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }
```

to something like this:

```
#left, #center, #right {
                float: left;
                margin: 0;
                min-width: 200px;
            }
```

Comment: Hey scott, I changed the margin to zero, but if your refer to the website there is now a gap on the right side.

Comment: What gap are you referring to?